# ThreadPoolExecutor fails when run with manage.py

Tags: django, python-3.4, python-multithreading

```
# test.py
# python 3.4.5

import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def a():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("success")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
executor.submit(a).result()
```

The above snippet works when run like

```
$ python test.py 
success
```

But fails when run like

```
$ python manage.py shell < test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tracking/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 101, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 395, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 354, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 7, in a
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Which is really strange to me. What is it about running the script with the `manage.py shell` command that results in the `time` module being undefined in the function `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking in the Django implementation (django/core/management/commands/shell.py line 83):

```
# Execute stdin if it has anything to read and exit.
# Not supported on Windows due to select.select() limitations.
if sys.platform != 'win32' and select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
    return
```

The developers did not add a `globals()` scope in the `exec()` method, that means you are importing time and ThreadPoolExecutor in the 'locals()' dictionary of the `handle()` scope (in shell.py) but after, when you try to use inside `a()` it tries to search in the `locals()` dictionary of the "a" scope and in the `globals()` dictionary so it throws an import error, you can see an example in this snippet:

```
command = """
import time
def b():
    time.sleep(1)
b()
"""
def a():
    exec(command)
a()
```

and try to change `exec(command)` by `exec(command, globals())`

Comment: Interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not working because you did not set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE` to your settings, and call `django.setup()` or set the path to sys.path.append('path/')
**(NOT SURE)**

### But these 2 options can work like a charm:

Either you import the module `time` inside the function:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def a():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print("success")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
executor.submit(a).result()
```

or just `import time` at the beginning like you did, and use the module as a `global` one:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def a():
    global time
    time.sleep(1)
    print("success")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
executor.submit(a).result()
```

Comment: I agree that's a solution, but it's still really weird to me that the original code works when run directly with `python`, but fails when run through `manage.py shell`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @FilipKilibarda I updated my answer, maybe it's more explicit now